# Build a Mass Spectrometer!

Tags: code-golf, chemistry

### Challenge

Given the high resolution molecular mass of an organic molecule, output the molecule's molecular formula.

### Explanation

The input will be a single number to three decimal places of precision, the relative molecular mass of the molecule.

Here, the molecular mass is defined as the sum of the masses of the atoms in the compound. Since you only are finding the molecular formulae of organic compounds, the atomic masses you need to know are:

- **C**, Carbon: 12.011
- **H**, Hydrogen: 1.008
- **O**, Oxygen: 15.999
- **N**, Nitrogen: 14.007

Your formula should only ever contain carbon, hydrogen, oxygen or nitrogen.

When writing the formula, it should take the form:

```
CaHbOcNd
```

Where the elements must be in that order (`C -> H -> O -> N`, so `C2O8N4H6` should be `C2H6O8N4`) and `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are numbers of the preceding element in the molecule (i.e. `C2` means that there are two carbon atoms in the molecule).

If `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` are zero, that element should not be included in the formula (e.g. `C2H6O2N0` should be `C2H6O2`). Finally, if `a`, `b`, `c` or `d` are one, you should not include the number in the formula (e.g. `C1H4` should be `CH4`).

The input will always be valid (i.e. there will be a molecule with that mass). If the input is ambiguous (multiple molecules have the same mass), you must only output one of the molecules. How you choose this molecule is up to you.

### Worked Example

Suppose the input is `180.156`, there is only one combination of the elements which can have this molecular mass:

```
12.011*6 + 1.008*12 + 15.999*6 + 14.007*0 = 180.156
```

So there are:

- 6 Carbons
- 12 Hydrogens
- 6 Oxygens
- 0 Nitrogens

Therefore, your output should be:

```
C6H12O6
```

### More Examples

```
Input -> Output

28.054 -> C2H4
74.079 -> C3H6O2
75.067 -> C2H5O2N
18.015 -> H2O
```

### Winning

Shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: What if the input is ambiguous?

Comment: @NoOneIsHere AFAIK the input should not be ambiguous, but I'll add that into the rules anyway.

Comment: Can input be taken as int (i.e., no period - ethene would be `28054`)

Comment: @StephenS Yes, it can

Comment: Can you reformat the test cases into something like `input -> output`? It's quite hard to read as-is.

Comment: `12.011` is the relative atomic mass of carbon, which is a weighted average of the relative isotopic masses of the isotopes. In a mass spectrometer, where different isotopes are distinguished, you should see exactly `12`. Similar for other atoms.

Comment: @LeakyNun Oh right. Whoops... :/

Comment: For a fun test, note that the input `672.336` has 24 possible solutions, including a pure-nitrogen and a pure-hydrogen solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Mathematica, 108 bytes

```
Print@@Join@@({Characters@"CHON",#}ᵀ/.a_/;Last@a<2:>Table@@a)&/@{12011,1008,15999,14007}~FrobeniusSolve~#&
```

Pure function expecting the input as an integer (1000 times the relative molecular mass); it prints all possible answers to STOUD (and returns an array of `Null`s).

The heavy lifting is done by the builtin `{12011,1008,15999,14007}~FrobeniusSolve~#`, which finds all nonnegative integer combinations of the hardcoded weights that equal the input. `{Characters@"CHON",#}ᵀ` puts each such combination in a form like `{{"C", 0}, {"H", 1}, {"O", 2}, {"N", 3}}`. (`ᵀ` is actually the 3-byte private Mathematica character U+F3C7.)

The transformation rule `/.a_/;Last@a<2:>Table@@a` changes pairs of the form `{x, 0}` to `{}` and pairs of the form `{x, 1}` to `{x}` (and spits out errors as it tries to apply to the whole expression as well). Then `Print@@Join@@` prints the result in the correct form, avoiding the need to cast the integers as strings and concatenate.

Comment: What's the result of 672336? :)

Comment: The `ᵀ` seems to be the wrong character. Should be ``.

Comment: Yeah, have to make the choice between easy to read and easy to cut/paste.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 242 bytes

```python
b=[12011,1008,15999,14007]
def p(m):
 if m in b:x=[0,]*4;x[b.index(m)]=1;return x
 elif m<1:return 0
 else:
  for i in range(4):
   x=p(m-b[i])
   if x:x[i]+=1;return x
  return 0
print''.join(a+`n`*(n>1)for n,a in zip(p(input()),'CHON')if n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#Vc3BisIwEAbge59ibk00Smap1rbWy148uQ9QCraYyohOQ6wQ9uVrArKwx//nn2/mvm7wSyMq1HqncFMUhcJM67xNLmYAKx6yTIAGeAAx9KWvG63aRVb5pl8TX4wPi7bGypnp5Rh8AuYe53ssP5WO1dMEBobRAUXIdXw1Ios2gK/Dm1XfUCtjDNe@9CEt/7Hwx1lHPKXp@jYSi2555vNC8AFl1Fl10f8lK6wgtq9JSKnS7@PPKZVBZjnP@UZv8zc)
Recursive function, the input is an integer (1000 times the relative molecular mass) <sup>thanks Stephen S for the idea</sup>

---

My machine took 40 segs to turn `672336` into `C33H115O3N8` with [this modified code](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#TY7RToMwGEbv@xS9o4WK7caGFOuNN17pAxCSQSimAl1hkDQue3ZsE5Vd/idf/nPWXhQl6MT1BmpRsB1ljDBKnwg7ZFlGWEJpWoJGttCgAXMAVQsHqDTs@STnZdKQbqz7Y10xlBuuuRUFJWWY5LaoY6Ubad2zUrD8d28BlL2fPzt3yvu4Mkbqxo3yzSL7i3QBsD1PUPm/U6U/JUp8FYSjQMPjZRlQjXHEPLHCJT/UhSrDEXvgBJZbd0dizLt4MU01S3QduL3huxJ4p3fXfwAwk9JzEMRfZ6VRFZ30KUT6hWEfpEnlk76VQQYpbZYZYUyC17eP9wA7scbrekx3@/3xBw). It contains a lookup table for hits/fails to reduce the amount of recursive calls and a optimization to count an element multiple times (if the mass is high enough)

Comment: Why does `180156` timeout when all of the test cases are so fast? (without the cache hit)

Comment: @BetaDecay hmm, could be `18015` instead?

Comment: Nope, `18015` is `H2O`, not `C6H12O6`

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>159</s> 158 bytes

Not exactly fast...

```js
w=>[...Array(w**4|0)].some((_,n)=>![12011,1008,15999,14007].reduce((p,c,i)=>p-c*(x[i]=n%w|!(n/=w)),w*1e3,x=[]))&&x.map((v,i)=>('CHON'[i]+v).slice(0,v)).join``
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

w=>[...Array(w**4|0)].some((_,n)=>![12011,1008,15999,14007].reduce((p,c,i)=>p-c*(x[i]=n%w|!(n/=w)),w*1e3,x=[]))&&x.map((v,i)=>('CHON'[i]+v).slice(0,v)).join``

console.log(f(28.054))  // -> C2H4
console.log(f(18.015))  // -> H2O
```

---

### Faster version, <s>174</s> 173 bytes

```js
w=>[...Array(w**3|0)].some((_,n)=>r=(d=w*1e3-14007*(a=n/w/w%w|0)-15999*(b=n/w%w|0)-12011*(c=n%w|0))%1008|d<0?0:[c,d/1008,b,a])&&r.map((v,i)=>('CHON'[i]+v).slice(0,v)).join``
```

#### All test cases

```js
let f=

w=>[...Array(w**3|0)].some((_,n)=>r=(d=w*1e3-14007*(a=n/w/w%w|0)-15999*(b=n/w%w|0)-12011*(c=n%w|0))%1008|d<0?0:[c,d/1008,b,a])&&r.map((v,i)=>('CHON'[i]+v).slice(0,v)).join``

console.log(f(180.156)) // -> C6H12O6
console.log(f(28.054))  // -> C2H4
console.log(f(74.079))  // -> C3H6O2
console.log(f(75.067))  // -> C2H5O2N
console.log(f(18.015))  // -> H2O
```